# Android -- Multiple, Simultaneous Streaming Audio

Tags: java, android, audio, streaming, media-player

I currently have the need to implement an application on the Android device that can open up live audio streams and play them back to the user. This is not a big deal, and I have successfully set up a streaming server and got it working for one file. My question is, however, how do I stream and play multiple audio files at once?

When I open up more than one stream (using MediaPlayer) and prepare and play each file, I only hear the audio from one file. I'm not sure this is currently possible, but I am hoping it is.

I looked into using SoundPool, but it seems to only be for local media and I MUST have this streaming as it is important for plaback speed (no wait time, etc.).

Any help or insight is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: but why u wanted to play them simultaneously.......?

Comment: I created and app to compose multi-media documents and if the user would like to play multiple audio files at once, then I would have liked to allow it. For example, fade one song out as another song fades in.

Comment: I haven't tried with multiple audio...... but did u used MediaPlayer.create() or new MediaPlayer() ?

Comment: Yeah, programatically you can load multiple audio files or streams, but they will not ACTUALLY work on the device as android does not support it. (as mentioned somewhere in the documentation that I really should have cited in my answer)

Comment: kkkkk i still think multiple can be played......... I did one thing to test it. I Started playing mp3 from built in player, then used a java code to stream another mp3 url, and both were playing simultaneously...... So it seems that two audio can be played....... You also test it........

Comment: that wasn't the problem.. get a test working with simultaneous streaming audio

Answer (score 1):

I was tinkering with an app previously and I had a similar issue and was able to fix it except I wasn't streaming the audio. Hopefully this can help, you will need to modify it for your purposes:

```
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.media.SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener;
import android.util.SparseIntArray;
```

**Instantiate a SoundPool and a SparseIntArray**
I am using sound files here, you will have to modify this part.

```
private static SoundPool soundPool;
private static SparseIntArray soundPoolMap;
public static final int S1 = R.raw.good_1, S2 = R.raw.bad_1,
        P1 = R.raw.power_1,
        P2 = R.raw.power_2, 
        P3 = R.raw.power_3, 
        P4 = R.raw.power_4, 
        P5 = R.raw.power_5, 
        WIN = R.raw.round_win;
```

**Initialize your sounds and add them to the map**

```
public static void initSounds(Context context)
{
    soundPool = new SoundPool(2, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
    soundPoolMap = new SparseIntArray(8);    

    soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                int status) {
            loaded = true;
        }
    });
    soundPoolMap.put(S1, soundPool.load(context, R.raw.good_1, 1));
    soundPoolMap.put(S2, soundPool.load(context, R.raw.bad_1, 2));

    soundPoolMap.put(P1, soundPool.load(context, R.raw.power_1, 3));
    soundPoolMap.put(P2, soundPool.load(context, R.raw.power_2, 4));
    soundPoolMap.put(P3, soundPool.load(context, R.raw.power_3, 5));
    soundPoolMap.put(P4, soundPool.load(context, R.raw.power_4, 6));
    soundPoolMap.put(P5, soundPool.load(context, R.raw.power_5, 7));

    soundPoolMap.put(WIN, soundPool.load(context, R.raw.round_win, 8));
}
```

**Play the sound**

```
public static void playSound(Context context, int soundID)
{
    float volume = 1;
    if(soundPool == null || soundPoolMap == null)
    {
       initSounds(context);
    }
    soundPool.play(soundPoolMap.get(soundID), volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
}
```

An example: playSound(this, P1);

Whats happening is I am using the [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) class and then mapping out audio streams with a [SparseIntArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseIntArray.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I was able to get simultaneous audio files to play only, as you said, when not streaming. Streaming seemed to break everything. However, it has been some time since I've worked in Android and I'm sure the APIs are much improved. Perhaps your example would work for streaming now.